# Qt6 desktop app and shared library with cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am trying to make a project with subdirectories using cmake.
When using qmake this mechanism was built in Qt creator.
The project contains a shared library and a desktop app.
Below is the structure of the project and cmake I have:

Main cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

project(contractapp)

add_subdirectory(contract-core)
add_subdirectory(contract-desktop)
```

Desktop app cmake:

```
project(contract-desktop LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# QtCreator supports the following variables for Android, which are identical to qmake Android variables.
# Check https://doc.qt.io/qt/deployment-android.html for more information.
# They need to be set before the find_package( ...) calls below.

#if(ANDROID)
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
#    if (ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
#        set(ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libcrypto.so
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libssl.so)
#    endif()
#endif()

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(contract-core REQUIRED)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        MainWindow.cpp
        MainWindow.h
        MainWindow.ui
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(contract-desktop
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(contract-desktop SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    else()
        add_executable(contract-desktop
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(contract-desktop PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)
```

Shared library cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(contract-core LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)

add_library(contract-core SHARED
  contract-core_global.h
  Person.cpp
  Person.h
)

target_link_libraries(contract-core PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core)

target_compile_definitions(contract-core PRIVATE CONTRACTCORE_LIBRARY)
```

My problem is that the desktop application does not see the library that I am making.

Comment: "My problem is that the desktop application does not see the library" - Please, elaborate that. Do you get an error when you built your application? Or do you get an error when you run your application? What **exact error message** do you get?

Comment: When i try include class from library i hava a errror this file not found.

Comment: Your *description* of the error message is very vague. Please, show (add to the question post) the exact error message you got.

Comment: By not providing "Findcontract-core.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "contract-core", but CMake did not find one. Could not find a package configuration file provided by "contract-core" with any of the following names: contract-coreConfig.cmake contract-core-config.cmake Add the installation prefix of "contract-core" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "contract-core_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "contract-core" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

Comment: This is my error when i add ```find_package(contract-core REQUIRED)```

Comment: As you can see, *comments* are badly suited for multiline information like error messages. Instead, such information should be added to the **question post** (by [edit]-ing it). On Stack Overflow it is the question post which should contain all information about the problem. Comments are used only for request this information. It is expected that you will edit your question post every time a comment asks about additional information. After modification is done, you may write a comment like "The question post has been updated" for notify the commenter.

Comment: As for `find_package`, then it is not needed for locate a library **created in the project** itself. CMake is already aware about all libraries in that project. If you want to link with some library, created in the project, just use its **target name**, as passed to the `add_library` call. In your case, for link the executable with the library just use  `target_link_libraries(contract-desktop PRIVATE contract-core)`.

Answer (score 1):

That library has to be copied to the same folder the application is in. Otherwise, each is in its own folder, and the application won't see it. Most likely you'd want to set the target folder for both binaries (the application and the library) to be some common build subfolder of both.